# How to go from a web2py api on EC2 to an AWS lambda serverless apps?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, web2py

A [web2py](http://web2py.com/) API approach is a complet project which need a server and provide endpoint to manage the business logic. Basicaly You will run such a webapp on an AWS EC2 and it fully makes sense that the scalability will be handle both via horizontal and vertical scaling.

Whereas, the [AWS lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/lambda/features/) in the other hand is a fully RESTFul approach to build an api app by triggering every needed python simplest actions. Which provide the serverless gain (meaning You actually use resources only if needed).

It is quite simple, for some project, to see that the serverless approach is more flexible and financially more interesting than the EC2 approach for scaling.

So my question is : if you already have a web2py api webapp déployed on an EC2 instance, **how to you go to deploy it in an aws lambda in other to gain the serverless aspect that aws lambda bring?** Do You need to fundamentaly reshape the code architecture of the web2py apps to properly gain the AWS lambda fashion ?

Comment: I got web2py working on AWS Lambda and it's been running for a long time on 2 live commercial production apps. Here is the multi-step deployment recipe. I hope this helps other avoid the weeks of pain I went through figuring it out: https://www-static-fund-team-com.s3.amazonaws.com/public_shared/AWS_Lambda_Web2py_Deployment_Recipe.html

Comment: I wonder if you can use zappa (works perfect for Django/Flask/wsgi): https://www.zappa.io/